# Pycharm pushing certain ide specific files automatically to remote

Tags: git, pycharm

I am experiencing a strange problem with the Git integration in Pycharm, the IDE automatically creates, commits and pushes certain files to upstream(master).

Following is the commit message which i see in my git log.
PY-2016.1.2 <#####@###### Create conda_packages.xml, IntelliLang.xml, git.xml, packages.xml, ignore.xml, ui.lnf.xml, laf.xml, web-browsers.xml, filetypes.xml, vcs.xml, editor.codeinsight.xml, notifications.xml, keymap.xml, multimarkdown.shared.xml, debugger.xml

I have tried everything like deleting these files and pushing the changes to upstream branch, however these files get added and pushed automatically.
It seems like if i change any setting etc some xml files get modified or created.

I am using Pycharm 2016.1.2 on Mac and any help on this problem would be really helpful.

Comment: sounds like pycharm is execute `git add .` or similar. Try using `git rm <files>` to remove them, commit the changes, the modify your `.gitignore` file to specify those files.

Comment: Did the exact same thing to stop the push for now. I wanted to know how can i stop it from doing this so that it doesnt create new files which are not in .gitignore list

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. Make sure you don't have your **git** repository url under File -> Settings Repository.

That has nothing to do with git, it's a repository where you can share your IDE config files with other developers so everyone runs the same IDE configuration.

Just remove the git repo url from there and you will be good to go.